# Compiling SFML Can't Be Finish: SFML/Audio/SoundRecorder.cpp In destructor error

Tags: sfml

I am at 82 % of compiling and it stops (use Linux OS), thus this is the screenshot.

[image: 1]

I want to use this SFML but why is it so hard to compile it and install it?

I try this :

```
grep "assert" SoundRecorder.cpp
```

at the so-called file

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are compiling SFML from scratch instead of grabbing the packages from your distribution? Secondly, what compiler version is this, so we can try to reproduce it?

Comment: And, in retrospect, the obvious question: does your copy of `cassert` actually define the `assert` macro?

Comment: @Botje I am using GCC-11.2.0 and I am not using Ubuntu or other popular Linux OS like OpenSUSE, etc. That is why I am compiling from source. It is LFS OS.

Comment: How to check this : `does your copy of cassert actually define the assert macro?` thanks..

Comment: Grep. Or a small standalone program that includes the `cassert` header and tries to call `asseert`.

Comment: When I type `grep -c "assert" SoundRecorder.hpp` or  `grep -c "cassert" SoundRecorder.hpp` they return `0` meaning no such word in the troublesome problem. Should I add `#include <cassert>` ?

Comment: I add the grep detail at my post above

Comment: If the SFML files did not contain assert your compiler would not be complaining about it. I meant grep the header file `cassert` for `assert`. Or, again, write and try to compile a test program that includes `cassert` and tries to call `assert`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a broken compiler installation. `assert()` is part of the `<cassert>` header, as correctly recognized by the compiler, yet for some reason it doesn't seem to correctly include it, as it can't find the symbol.

I'd suggest to reinstall the compiler and see if that resolves the issue.

You may, as @Botje suggested also double check whether the defined `<cassert>` header (which include other headers), actually include an implementation of `assert()`, but would be odd, if it didn't. On Linux you should usually find them in `/usr/include/c++/<version>/` or alternatively run `g++ -v -v -v` which should list the location of the include directory as well.

Comment: I want to know how to find out the `<cassert>` header include the implementation of `assert()`? I will reinstall the compiler then..

Comment: I've added said information to the answer above